# Why didn't we have inflation when the theory of everything and GUTS broke symmetry?

Tags: cosmology

Inflation seems to have occurred when the symmetry breaking of the electroweak occurred.   But do we know of any reason why we did not have inflation when gravity separated from the other forces or the strong and electroweak separated?  Are all these other symmetry breakings associated with the Higgs field and a mexican hat energy distribution.  Sorry it is all a bit confusing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Physics SE